# Looking For an Applock

Tags: android, lockscreen

Due to recent security concerns, I'm looking for an Applock app. However, apps being apps, you can't trust 'em all. So, I am looking for:

**Absolute Must-haves**

- Applock capabilities (duh)
- Minimal adverts

**would love it if....**

- App could be hidden from **stock** launcher.
- It can be password protected.

**Prefer, but not needed**

- Perhaps the ability to take pictures Of failed **and** successful attempts.
- Automated Emails/SMS when a picture is taken.

Comment: Have a look at  - https://www.whattechsays.com/best-applock-for-android-free-download/